# Any Javascript Library or Jquery plugin for calculating Polygon's Area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let say I have a polygon with n points. Now I need to calculate the polygon area? Is there is any library exist or a custom function exist?

Comment: The formula to calculate the area is not too complex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_area#Area_and_centroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what you're looking for conceptually: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polyarea/

and the javascript code: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polyarea/javascript.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
* @param {Array} points
*/

function getArea ( points  ){
if( points.length <= 2 ){
  return 0;
}
var res = 0;
for( var i = 2; i < points.length; ++i){
    var v1x = points[i].x - points[0].x;
    var v1y = points[i].y - points[0].y;
    var v2x = points[i].x - points[1].x;
    var v2y = points[i].y - points[1].y;
    res += v1x*v2y - v2x*v1y;    
}

return Math.abs(res);
}
```